# Passport.js local redirect issue (Express 500 error)

Tags: passport.js

I have a form that has two fields username and passwort, I submit it using post request.

The route

```
app.post('/login', users.login)
```

If my login function is

```
login: passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}),
```

Then after incorrect login url in address string changes to /login (or redirect addres that is in falureRedict), but there is no form page, but 500 Express error page.

If I use custom auth code like:

```
login: function(req, res, next){

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user){
        if (err || !user){
            res.redirect('/login')

        } else {
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                console.log('user logged')
                if (err){
                    res.redirect('/login')
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/')
                }

            });
        }
    })(req, res, next)

},
```

What is the issue with my first variant of the code?

Comment: Could you share how did you resolved this?

Comment: Not sure. Think, left it alone.

Comment: ok. I found the reason. There was some unhandled internal error. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What was your solution exactly?